# Tracking Facebook Apprequests on iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have Facebook connect set up for my iphone app and am able to successfully send apprequests. What I want to do is track whenever an apprequest recipient clicks the notification to either install my app or open my app.

When the recipient already has the app installed, I can track that they opened the app from Facebook by looking at the URL in the 'application openURL' method in AppDelegate. But if the recipient does not have my app installed, clicking the notification brings them to the app store to install my app. Is there anyway for me to track that this install came from a FB apprequest? Or assuming they do NOT install my app, is there a way for me to track that?

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 5/22/2012, there is no way to accurately track installs coming from Facebook, because iTunes will truncate the URL. This was confirmed for me by a FB employee.

A rough workaround is to save all the fbuids that are sent requests for the past X hours or so. If anyone using your app FB connects within that time frame with a matching fbuid, you just assume the install came from the original FB request.